# multiple job plugin running job multiple time - Jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I'm using [multijob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin), Where I have created a Job using it and configured 2 Job in it as shown here:

[image]

I've configured to run both job sequentially. But while I do build Its execution order is
Job 1
Job 2
Then Again
Job 2
Job 1

I want it to be configure, the execution should be only one time Job 1 and Job 2. How do I configure here ?

Comment: what is your purpose? you want to run a job after first job right?

Comment: Yes, I have categorized some test in 2 different job and Now I want to run both 2 job one after another using this plugin but it running twice

Comment: Okay let me check i think you are configuring it in wrong way

Comment: i have added an answer for this. Please check it and let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below configuration working for me.

I have used [Multijob Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) and configured my both job in different phases as shown Here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Steps to trigger multiple job using **`Multi Job Plug In`:**

- In your first job that is "Rcontact_Dashboard_testSuite" click on **`Add build step`**
- Then select **`trigger/call builds o other project`**
- on **`Projects to build`** field just type "**Rcontact_Main_TestSuite**" that is your second job.

Then build the first job
This will run your first job after that it will trigger your second job.

Hop this will solve your issue. let me know your feedback.

Comment: @NarendraR i think you are running first job in multijob phase under the add build step. Just create the first job as free style job. add your first jobs configuration then just do the above.

Comment: @NarendraR from the details of the question i understand that you have now three job. and from the first job you are calling two job. No need to do this. You can trigger the "Rcontact_Main_TestSuite" job from the add build step of "Rcontact_Dashboard_testSuite" job following the above procedure

Comment: i have  now 2 job,  job one and job two  and job 2 configured in job 1 add post build step as you told but still same issue in this case too

Comment: @NarendraR can you share the screen shot of the current job configuration of both the jobs